# Implementing the GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to get a GUI which should have two rows and two columns [ 1st column with labels and the second column with text fields]. I have written the below code but i am unable to get it into columns and rows.Could you please help to make it into columns and row.

```
 public void showstate(){

       MyPanel b=new MyPanel();
       f.setBounds(50, 50, 800, 600);
       f.add(b);
       b.updateState(result);
       f.setVisible(true);
       System.out.println("Number of times AC is on:" + AcCounter);
       System.out.println("Number of times Heater is on:" + HeaterCounter);


}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField t;
    private JTextField v;


    public MyPanel() {
    //setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));


    JLabel l = new JLabel("THE STATUS OF AC IS");


    this.add(l);
    t = new JTextField("<html><table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><br></br></table></html>");

    this.add(t);
    //JLabel l = new JLabel("");  
   l.setBounds(100, 100, 30, 30);

    JLabel p = new JLabel("THE STATUS OF HEATER IS");


    p.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    p.setHorizontalAlignment(30);
    p.setBounds(100, 200, 30, 30);
    this.add(p);
    v = new JTextField("<td></td></tr></table></html>");

    this.add(v);



  // JLabel m = new JLabel("<html> <span><br><br><br>Accounter</br></br></br></span>    </html> ",JLabel.CENTER);


  //m.setBounds(100, 300, 30, 30);

 // JLabel n = new JLabel("<html> <span><br><br><br>Heatercounter</br></br></br></span></html> ", JLabel.CENTER);

    //n.setBounds(100, 400, 30, 30);


    t.setBounds(300, 400, 30, 50);

  //  q = new JTextField("");
  //  w = new JTextField("");

   // this.add(m);
 //   this.add(q);
   // this.add(n);
 //   this.add(w);

}

public void updateState(String result) {

    String ac, ab;
   //     double AcIsOn,HeaterIsOn;

    if ("aboveHt".equals(result) || "coolAir".equals(result)) {
        ac = "cooler on";
        AcCounter++;
    } else {
        ac = "cooler off";
    }


     if(temperature==72){ 
        ab = "Heater off";
    }
     else  if ("belowHt".equals(result)) {
         ab = "Heater on";
         HeaterCounter++;
        // AcCounter=1;
     }
    else {
        ab = "Heater off";
    }                                               
      t.setText(ac);
     v.setText(ab);

}        
}
```

I am getting output as **The Status Of Ac** *JTextField* **The Status Of Heater** *JTextField* in a single row

Comment: Use a layout manager. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of ways you could achieve this.

As has already being stated, you should be taking advantage of proper layout managers when using Swing, the Swing API has being designed around them (or with them in mind).

Another way would be to use a `JTable`

[image]

Caveats: This is a very simple example and assumes a single row table.  Personally, I prefer to allow multiple rows, but this gets the basic idea across...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                MonitorTableModel model = new MonitorTableModel();
                model.setAcStatus("Off");
                model.setHeaterStatus("On");

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);                

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MonitorTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String acStatus;
        private String heaterStatus;

        public void setAcStatus(String acStatus) {
            this.acStatus = acStatus;
            fireTableCellUpdated(1, 0);
        }

        public void setHeaterStatus(String heaterStatus) {
            this.heaterStatus = heaterStatus;
            fireTableCellUpdated(1, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return column == 0 ? "AC Status" : "Heater Status";
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 0 ? acStatus : heaterStatus;
        }

    }        
}
```

Check out [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: It worked good. Can i change the color? like when the acstatus is off,off should be red and when the acstatus is on,on should be in green. Could you please help with that. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the linked tutorial.  There are examples of how to use custom cell renderers

Comment: You have to love the bravery of people who down vote without having the curtsey to leave a comment as to why they felt it necessary to do so. It fails to help anybody learn or the opportunity to improve this or other answers into the future. Like I said, real brave

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to layout things in Swing is to use Layout Managers. Your panel has a default layout of FlowLayout, which puts all components in one row, like you are observing.

You can use either a GridLayout or a combination of BoxLayout or something more complex. Look at [the tutorials for Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to make your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read about [LayoutManager.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) It helps you to build your GUI.

And here is example with `GridLayout` 1 column has 2 labels and 2 column 2 fields:

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

public Example() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("l1");
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("l2");
    JTextField f1 = new JTextField();
    JTextField f2 = new JTextField();

    add(l1);
    add(f1);
    add(l2);
    add(f2);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String...strings ){
    Example e = new Example();
}

}
```